# Add polygons to PostGres to be queried by Nominatim

Tags: postgis, postgresql, tiger, nominatim

I'm trying to build out a geocoder that also returns the correct legislative district information from this data:
http://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger.html

I've got OSM data imported into a PostGres database and I'm using Nominatim to query that information, but I cannot figure out how to lay the above information on top of that and return it via Nominatim. After reading a lot, I'm assuming it would make sense to layer the legislative district information as polygons.

I'm not looking for the polygon to be mapped as the usage will be strictly API. What type of geodata file do I need to download? And how would I go about getting it included in the queried elements of Nominatim?

Comment: Does this API help? http://gis.govtrack.us/map/demo/cd-2012/

Comment: It looks like they're doing something similar and offer an OSM example. But I cannot see how they're doing it.